# Samba 4 can't copy from previous version in Windows

Tags: linux, windows, samba, snapshot

**HW:**
HP server ML110G9

**SW:**
Fileserver CT (Proxmox host) - debian 11 - Samba version 4.13.13-Debian
UserPC - Windows 8 / Windows 11

**ZFS snapshot format:**
data/subdata@GMT-2023.07.05-19.41.00

**smb.conf:**

```
    vfs objects = shadow_copy2 acl_xattr
    acl_xattr:ignore system acls = yes
    shadow: format = GMT-%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S
    shadow: sort = desc
    shadow: snapdir = .zfs/snapshot
    shadow: basedir = /data
    shadow: share_root = /data/subdata
    shadow: localtime = yes
    zfsacl:expose_snapdir=true
    veto files = /.windows/.mac/
```

**Samba log:**

```
  root opened file PngItem_1468479.png {@GMT-2023.07.05-23.41.00} read=No write=No (numopen=3)
[2023/07/05 17:21:28.422995,  2] ../../source3/smbd/close.c:824(close_normal_file)
  root closed file PngItem_1468479.png {@GMT-2023.07.05-23.41.00} (numopen=2) NT_STATUS_OK
[2023/07/05 17:21:30.401392,  2] ../../source3/smbd/open.c:1524(open_file)
  root opened file PngItem_1468479.png {@GMT-2023.07.05-23.41.00} read=Yes write=No (numopen=4)
[2023/07/05 17:21:30.430323,  2] ../../source3/smbd/trans2.c:3646(smbd_do_qfsinfo)
  stat of . failed (No such file or directory)
[2023/07/05 17:21:30.432968,  2] ../../source3/smbd/trans2.c:3646(smbd_do_qfsinfo)
  stat of . failed (No such file or directory)
[2023/07/05 17:21:30.435970,  2] ../../source3/smbd/trans2.c:3646(smbd_do_qfsinfo)
  stat of . failed (No such file or directory)
```

**Problem description:**

1. When i delete a file and open previous version through the tab in windows, I am able to open png file, not vsd (for now this files i have tested)
2. I am not able to copy any files/folders from the snapshot that opened when i pres open from the properties/previous version tab to my local machine.

```
Popup error Title: Item Not Found

Popup error message: Could not find this item

This is no longer located in \\192.168.6.179\subdata\subdata(\\192.168.6.179). Verify the item's location and try again.
```

3. I am able to go to .zfs/snapshot folder through smb and copy the file successfully to User PC.
4. I would like to transfer away from windows to linux, which i really need the shadow copy to work.

- I have googled through the internet, i used ChatGPT for 2days straight and was not able to resolve this problem.
- When i tested Truenas VM with same conditions, it worked right away, i tryed to export smb.conf from truenas but was not able to find any mentions on shadow_copy2 in the conf files to be able copy/paste...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the samba package. After upgrading samba to
**4.17.9+dfsg-0+deb12u3~bpo11+1**
with **bullseye-backports**
everything is working :)